# How to get android activity or controls touch count?

Tags: android

**I want to get activity or any control element's touch counts.**
Like Android 4.2 on nexus Developer options Enable while touching 7 times.

What is the suitable event to handle it ?

Comment: have you tried to implement the onTouch method?

Comment: I cannot find @override method for `onTouch`

Comment: public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
We are talking about an activity right?

Comment: Yes Got it.. you are talking override event without setting listeners ? it's work but it count 2 times for one touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting 2 count's because the touch event are called every time a touch event is snet, like tump down and tump up (for example)

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        //add here the counter if you want when screen pressed
                    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        //add here the counter if you want when touch released
                    break;
    default:
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [View.OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html), overriding the onTouch method :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // increment counter
            break;
    }
}
```